# Ожидание выполнения асинхронной функции внутри асинхронной функции

Tags: python, asyncio, telethon

Через библиотеку telethon программа реагирует на новые сообщения в канале. Действия после получения нового сообщения требуют некоторого времени. Если в этот промежуток в канале выйдет новое сообщение, то его обработка будет некорректной. Нужно дождаться завершения обработки первого сообщения. То есть поставить обработку нового сообщения паузу до тех пор, пока не будет обработано первое.

На сообщения реагирую так

`@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=[PeerChannel(config.CHANNEL_INTERCEPTION)]))`

Answer (score 1):

Для такой синхронизации функций используй [asyncio.Semaphore](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#asyncio.Semaphore). Параметр показывает сколько раз одновременно можно пройти семафор.

```
sem = asyncio.Semaphore(1)

@....
async def foo():
    async with sem:
        await do_something_exclusive()
```